# How to restore SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO DATABASE to PC Server to SQLEXPRESS Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2008 R2. I have used my pc's name(For example, MY-PC) as a server name to make databases. Now how can I get the database I created in my pc's named server, when I select .\sqlexpress as a server.

The error it shows when I tried to restore in .\sqlexpress from .bak file:
Restore failed for Server 'MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Additional Information:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.2531. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restore the database in the above scenario - as per the error, the backup was taken on a **SQL Server 2008R2** instance, and you are trying to restore it on a **SQL Server 2008** instance - backup files are not backwards compatible.

You can see this from the error message:

**10.50.1600** is **SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM**

**10.00.2531** is **SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1**

See the following Microsoft article for details on SQL Server version numbers:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Comment: I am using 2008R2. For backup and restore both.

Comment: Edited answer with details from error and link to version number information.